# How can I see the value of a variable without hovering over it in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Hovering over variables to see the value of a variable, cell, or built-in function result doesn't seen to work for me very often. While hovering I often see the value of a wrong variable, or just nothing at all. Is there a way to see the value of variables, cells and functions without hovering over them? I searched for it but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: open `Locals Window` from Menu >> View >> Locals. Or use `Debug.Print variable_name` to get variable result in `Immediate Window`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the VBE, whether in or out of break mode right-click the var and choose Add watch... This will also open the Watch window ([alt]+V,H).

[image: watch_window]

Expand (aka *drill-down*) into the properties and values by clicking the **+** symbol(s) to expand a watched item. Click **-** to contract the item and make room for other information.

As you step through your code with [F8], the Watch window will keep the value and properties constantly updated.

Comment: How can I use this to see the value of `shtD.Cells(i, j - 1)` for example? Or do I have to save that value into a variable first?

Comment: Hmmm. You could `Set rng = shtD.Cells(i, j - 1)` but in a loop, `i` and `j` are going to change. You would have to keep setting it and resetting it within the second nested loop (assume for `j`).